# Error creating context 'spring.root': Could not load type from string value

Tags: .net, spring, console-application, spring.net

i'm working on .net project,

since from last 2 days getting following error which is referring other assembly `Valhalla.Core` but not getting exact reason of error.

no changes are made recently help me to identify reason.

```
{"Error creating context 'spring.root': Could not load type from string value 'Valhalla.Core.Events.Implementation.EventListenerManager, Valhalla.Core.Events.Implementation'."}

{"Could not load type from string value 'Valhalla.Core.Events.Implementation.EventListenerManager, Valhalla.Core.Events.Implementation'.":""}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You mention that the assembly name is Valhalla.Core, yet the type qualifier in the error message indicates an assembly named Valhalla.Core.Events.Implementations. The part after the comma is the assembly name, which is the exact name of the relevant dll.

Search your XML configuration files for

```
type="Valhalla.Core.Events.Implementation.EventListenerManager, Valhalla.Core.Events.Implementations"
```

And replace it with

```
type="Valhalla.Core.Events.Implementation.EventListenerManager, Valhalla.Core"
```

Some other things you can investigate:

- Which assembly contains `EventListenerManager`?
- Is this assembly present in the output directory?
- In what namespace is `EventListenerManager`?

Comment: Hi thanks for reply `Valhalla.Core.Events.Implementation` dll is also with me but i have not refer it, need to refer this or nor?

Comment: refer that assembly also no luck will try your solution on which xml configuration ? this is console app checked into app.config dont found any entry

Comment: You don't need to reference the assembly in your visual studio projects. I'll put some more pointers in my answer.